# disable individual buttons on a lispworks capi:push-button-panel

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, mscapi, lispworks

I'm working on a Connect Four game using common lisp and the [LispWorks CAPI](http://www.lispworks.com/products/capi.html).  I'm finished with the interface except for one thing: I use push-buttons (in a push-button-panel) to drop pieces into the columns, and I'd like to disable a button once its corresponding column is full.  I'm relatively new to lisp, and I especially don't understand the object-oriented stuff, so I can't figure out how to do it.

A single push-button can be created thisly:

```
(setf my-button (capi:contain
                 (make-instance 'capi:push-button
                                :text "Button!")))
```

And disabled thusly:

```
(capi:apply-in-pane-process 
 my-button #'(setf capi:button-enabled) nil my-button)
```

A push-button-panel is created similarly, except it takes an `:items` argument that is a list of buttons (or data, which the CAPI will create buttons out of) to be in the panel.

I simply need to know how to disable the individual buttons of a push-button-panel.  Also it would be nice if you could explain what is happening in that last piece of code there, because I don't understand it at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of searching through the manual reveals [this function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CAPRM/html/capiref-361.htm#26639), which allows you to enable/disable one or more elements in a `push-button-panel`. Also, the code you wanted explained calls the function `(setf capi:button-enabled)` with the arguments `nil` and `my-button`. However, this function is called in the "process" associated with your button. (see the documentation [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CAPRM/html/capiref-12.htm#pgfId-2230922)

(P.S. If you need help understanding the "object oriented stuff", [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) might be a useful resource)